# SQL query does not return expected results (Join 3 tables)

Tags: mysql

I'm solving a Codewars' problem on SQL but I can get what I neeed

> Given film_actor and film tables from the DVD Rental sample database
>   find all movies both Sidney Crowe (actor_id = 105) and Salma Nolte
>   (actor_id = 122) cast in together and order the result set
>   alphabetically.

```
Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
title       | character varying(255)      | not null
film_id     | smallint                    | not null


 Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
actor_id    | smallint                    | not null
film_id     | smallint                    | not null
last_update | timestamp without time zone | not null



Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
actor_id    | integer                     | not null 
first_name  | character varying(45)       | not null
last_name   | character varying(45)       | not null
last_update | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

This is the result I'm supposed to get:

```
title
Antitrust Tomatoes
Clones Pinocchio
Oz Liaisons
Siege Madre
```

but I'm getting this:

```
Title
Alaska Phantom
Alien Center
American Circus
Antitrust Tomatoes
Artist Coldblooded
Candidate Perdition
Clones Pinocchio
.....
```

This is my query

```
select title from ( film 
inner join film_actor on film.film_id=film_actor.film_id)
inner join actor on film_Actor.actor_id=actor.actor_id
where actor.actor_id=122 or actor.actor_id=105
```

Comment: You are getting films where either one of the two actor_id matches.

Comment: You have an `OR` when you should be using `AND`

Comment: If you use AND, you wouldn't get any results since no rows will match both conditions.

Comment: @clinomaniac, Agreed. Need to get the results of each `actor_id`, then match the `title` for each dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do something like this...

```
SELECT f.title
FROM film f INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
WHERE fa.actor_id IN (105, 122)
GROUP BY f.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY f.title
```

The count(*) will be equal to the number of actors you need to match. If you need to join using names then you need to add the actor table as well, otherwise the id's are in the film_actor table. What you are doing here is counting all the movies with either one of the actors available and then seeing which movie is listed twice (the number of actors). Any movie that is listed as many times as the number of actors is the one with all the required actors in that movie.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also find this solution to be very interesting :`select title
  from film
  where film_id in (
    select film_id from film_actor where actor_id = 105
    intersect
    select film_id from film_actor where actor_id = 122 )`